# Blackjack Strategy

Tags: java, beginner, game, playing-cards

I am creating a Blackjack simulator in Java in order to better understand the language.  I have written the basic strategy section for a player and it is terribly long.

Is there a better way to do this other than `if`/`else` statements?  I know a switch might work but that wouldn't make it much shorter.  The reality is that there are quite a few situations and reactions when playing Blackjack.

```
public void play(Card upCard){

    //Use this block to check for situations that happen right after dealing
    //like blackjack, doubledown and splits.  
    if (getHand().size() == 2){
        if (getHandValue() == 21){
            blackjack();
        }

        //scenario with ace as one of the cards.
        else if (getHand().get(0).getName().equals("Ace") |
                getHand().get(1).getName().equals("Ace")){

            //Check if both cards are aces, always split aces
            if (getHand().get(0).getName().equals("Ace") &
                getHand().get(1).getName().equals("Ace")){

                split();
            }

            //Double down on Ace, 2 against dealer 5 or 6
            else if(getHand().get(0).getName().equals("Two") |
                    getHand().get(1).getName().equals("Two") &
                    upCard.getValue() >= 5 & upCard.getValue() <= 6
                    ){
                doubleDown();
                return;

            }

            //Double down on Ace, 3 against dealer 5 or 6 (same as 2, broken
            //up to make code easier to read
            else if(getHand().get(0).getName().equals("Three") |
                    getHand().get(1).getName().equals("Three") &
                    upCard.getValue() >= 5 & upCard.getValue() <= 6
                    ){
                doubleDown();
                return;
            }

            //Double down on Ace 4 against 4,5, or 6.
            else if(getHand().get(0).getName().equals("Four") |
            getHand().get(1).getName().equals("Four") &
            upCard.getValue() >= 4 & upCard.getValue() <= 6
            ){
                doubleDown();
                return;
            }        

            //Double down on Ace, 5 against 4,5, or 6, same as 4, broken up
            //to make code easier to read
            else if(getHand().get(0).getName().equals("Five") |
            getHand().get(1).getName().equals("Five") &
            upCard.getValue() >= 4 & upCard.getValue() <= 6
            ){
                doubleDown();
                return;
            }

            //Double down on Ace, 6 against dealer 3-6
            else if(getHand().get(0).getName().equals("Six") |
            getHand().get(1).getName().equals("Six") &
            upCard.getValue() >= 3 & upCard.getValue() <= 6
            ){
                doubleDown();
                return;
            }

            //Double down on Ace, 7 against dealer 3-6, same as 6, broken up
            //to make code easier to read
            else if(getHand().get(0).getName().equals("Seven") |
            getHand().get(1).getName().equals("Seven") &
            upCard.getValue() >= 3 & upCard.getValue() <= 6
            ){
                doubleDown();
                return;
            }                
        }


        //If pair of 2's, split if dealer card is between 4 and 7
        else if (getHand().get(0).getName().equals("Two") &
            getHand().get(1).getName().equals("Two") &
            upCard.getValue() >= 4 & upCard.getValue() <= 7){

            split();
        }

        //If pair of 3's, split if dealer card is between 4 and 7
        //Same as pair of 2's, broken up for ease of reading code
        else if (getHand().get(0).getName().equals("Three") &
            getHand().get(1).getName().equals("Three") &
            upCard.getValue() >= 4 & upCard.getValue() <= 7){

            split();
        }

        //If pair of 6's, split against dealer's 3-6
        else if (getHand().get(0).getName().equals("Six") &
            getHand().get(1).getName().equals("Six") &
            upCard.getValue() >= 3 & upCard.getValue() <= 6){

            split();
        }

        //If pair of 7's, split against dealer's 2-7
        else if (getHand().get(0).getName().equals("Seven") &
            getHand().get(1).getName().equals("Seven") &
            upCard.getValue() >= 2 & upCard.getValue() <= 7){

            split();
        }

        //Check if both cards are 8's, always split 8's
        else if (getHand().get(0).getName().equals("Eight") &
            getHand().get(1).getName().equals("Eight")){
            split();
        }

        //If pair of 9's, split against dealer's 2-6 and 8-9
        //handles 2-6
        else if (getHand().get(0).getName().equals("Nine") &
            getHand().get(1).getName().equals("Nine") &
            upCard.getValue() >= 2 & upCard.getValue() <= 6){

            split();
        }

        //If pair of 9's, split against dealer's 2-6 and 8-9
        //handles 8-9
        else if (getHand().get(0).getName().equals("Nine") &
            getHand().get(1).getName().equals("Nine") &
            upCard.getValue() >= 8 & upCard.getValue() <= 9){

            split();
        }

    }

    while(getHandValue() <= 17 & !busted()){
        if (getHandValue() <= 8){
            hit();
        }

        else if (getHandValue() == 9){

            if(upCard.getValue() >= 3 & upCard.getValue() <= 6){
                doubleDown();
                return;
            }

            else{ //dealer up card is 2 or 7 or above
                hit();
            }
        }

        else if (getHandValue() == 10){

            if(upCard.getValue() >= 2 & upCard.getValue() <= 9){
                doubleDown();
                return;
            }

            else{ //dealer up card is 10 or Ace
                hit();
            }
        }

        else if (getHandValue() == 11){

            if(upCard.getValue() >= 2 & upCard.getValue() <= 10){
                doubleDown();
                return;
            }

            else{ //dealer up card is Ace
                hit();
            }
        }

        else if (getHandValue() == 12){

            //upcard is 2,3 or greater than or eqaual to 7.
            //stand otherwise, no else statement needed for standing
            if(upCard.getValue() <= 3 & upCard.getValue() >= 7){
                hit();
            }
        }

        else if (getHandValue() >= 13 & getHandValue() <= 16){

            if(upCard.getValue() >= 7){
                hit();
            }
        }

        //hand is at least 17
        else{
            return;
        }
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Two words.

**Lookup tables.**

Here's one I randomly found on the internet:

[image: from www.blackjack-strategycard.com/blackjack-strategy-rules-multi-deck.htm]

All you gotta do is make a 2D array, populate it with the right values (enum?), and alter your `play(Card upCard)` method to use the lookup table.

That solves your complexity issue, your implicit data storage (you're trying to algorithmically map the values of 3 variables (card 1, card 2, dealer up card) to a lot of different values), and it should be a speedup too. Plus, what are blackjack explanations doing in your code?

Note that you might have to split your lookup table in three sections: One for the doubles, one for the case where you have an ace, and one for the last case, where you need to use the total of your hand.

---

That said, looking at your code, there's some things that could also look a bit differently:

```
getHand().get(0).getName().equals("Ace") |
getHand().get(1).getName().equals("Ace")
```

Seems like this could get wrapped into a method called `containsCard(String name)`. I'm worried about a single pipe though - Isn't it `||`?

```
getHand().get(0).getName().equals("Ace") &
getHand().get(1).getName().equals("Ace")
```

Same thing here: this could be `boolean hasPair()`. Also, isn't it `&&`?

```
getHand().get(0).getName().equals("Two") |
getHand().get(1).getName().equals("Two") &
upCard.getValue() >= 5 & upCard.getValue() <= 6
```

This looks like it contains a bug.

Let's rephrase it:

```
firstCard is "Two" |
secondCard is "Two" &
(dealerCard is 5 or dealerCard is 6)
```

Notice the problem? (I'm not sure if using `|` compared to `||` prevents this from becoming a bug, but...) `||` short-circuit evaluates. Basically, if `firstCard is "Two"` is true, then the whole if statement is true. Whoops.

Comment: Thanks @Pimgd.  I will have a look at this, certainly easier than typing each case out one at a time.  As far as the explanations, it is so I know which line does what without having to read the code.  After staring at it for so long the text helps.

Comment: @user2926358 updated my answer with some details about the code, because you're also doing some things that I consider strange.

Comment: Using `||` or `&&` instead of only a single character is to short-circuit. So if you can determine the result from the first operand, the second operand is not evaluated. I would say it is better practice in cases like this to use the short-circuiting version.

Comment: Even then, `|` or `||`, it doesn't change the result here. Because you still end up with `true OR something else`, which is true. So that's a bug.

Comment: That's actually not a bug, it is far from ideal code.  The statement you used as an example is found within an if statement that is true only if one of the cards is an Ace.  However, I didn't create a method to remember which of the two cards is the ace, so I do the check again, on both cards, for the card I am looking for.  This is confusing and hardly a great way to do this.

Comment: That's still a hidden bug. Why? Because it's either left OR (right AND (dealer card 5 OR dealer card 6)). Guess what happens at dealer card 7. That's right. Whether you have 2 A or A2 determines whether you'll double down or hit. And that's a bug in my opinion.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean after taking a break from the code.  Definitely a problem.  I will fix it by putting the or statement in parentheses.